# How to separate flask files when two files depend on each other?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to develop a database driven flask app.
I have an `api.py` file which has the flask app, api and SQLAlchemy db objects and a `users.py` file which contains the routes ands code to create a database table.

In the `users.py` file, there's a `UserManager` Resource which has the routes. I have to add this resource to the API from this file.

So `users.py` needs to import the db and the api from the `api.py` file and `api.py` needs to serve the flask app so it has all the variables `users.py` needs, but `api.py` also needs to import `users.py` in order to use it as a flask blueprint.

`api.py`:

```
...
from user import user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(user)
api = Api(app)
...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`users.py`:

```
from api import api

user = Blueprint('user', __name__, template_folder='templates')

db = SQLAlchemy(api.app)
ma = Marshmallow(api.app)

class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(32))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    ...
...

class UserManager(Resource):
    @user.route('/get/<user_id>', methods = ['GET'])
    def get_user(user_id):
        ...
```

This of course results in errors due to circular imports. Question is, how do I separate the flask files with the routes from the api file when the blueprint has dependencies from the api (the db and the api objects)

I also somehow have to do something like `api.add_resource(UserManager, '/api/users')` but I'm not sure where that'd go given the circular import.

Tried reducing dependencies between two files, but couldn't achieve described goal without doing a 2 way import.

Either trying to get 2 way import to work or still have same structure of separate files with routes but using 1 way import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known problem in flask. The solution is to use [application factories](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/).

[Cookiecutter Flask](https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask) does this really well and offers a good template. It is well worth to check out their repo and try to understand what they are doing.

Assuming you have a folder `app` and this folder contains a file `__init__.py` and your other files `user.py`, etc.

1. Create a file `app/extensions.py` with this content and any other extension you need to initialize.

```py
...
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
...
```

2. Import the `db` object (which was created, but not initialized) in the files where you need it.

```py
from app.extensions import db
```

3. In your `app/api.py` file

```py
from flask import Flask
from app.extensions import db
from app.user import user as user_bp

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app

def register_extensions(app):
    """Register Flask extensions."""
    db.init_app(app)
    return None

def register_blueprints(app):
    """Register Flask blueprints."""
    app.register_blueprint(user_bp)
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Add stuff based on this approach as needed.